# Perl regexp use of uninitialized pattern patch

Tags: regex, perl

My script loads some stuff from some files in some arrays, you enter a text from the keyboard, the script searches the relevant part of the text in those arrays, if it finds it, it does something, if not, well, another thing, at least in theory.

I get the following errors:

```
Use of uninitialized value in pattern match (m//) at emo_full_dynamic.pl line 120, <STDIN> chunk 2.
Modification of a read-only value attempted at emo_full_dynamic.pl line 121, <STDIN> chunk 2.
line 120 =  $plm3 =~ /arr_(\w+.txt)/;
```

My problem, I think, is at `$plm3 =~ /arr_(\w+.txt)/;`. I used it so that I can store the name of an array in `$1`.

Here's my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;

$idx = 0;
$oldsep = $/;

opendir(DIR, 'c:/downloads/text_files/arrs/');
@files = readdir(DIR);

while ($idx <= $#files )
    {
      $value = $files[$idx];
      if ( $value !~ m/^arr/i)
        {
           splice @files, $idx, 1;
         }
      else
        {
          $idx++;
         }
     }

foreach $plm (@files)
  {
    if($plm =~ m/txt$/)
      {
        open(ARR, "C:/downloads/text_files/arrs/$plm") or die $!;
        while(<ARR>)
          {             {
        chomp($_);
            $plm =~ m/arr_(\w+).txt/;
            push(@{$1}, $_);
           }
        close ARR;
       }
   }

$plm = 0;
$idx = 0;

$stare = <STDIN>;
chomp($stare);
while($stare)
    {
      foreach $plm2 (@files)
        {
        if($plm2 =~ m/txt$/)
              {
                $plm2 =~ m/arr_(\w+).txt/;
                if(grep $stare  =~ m/$_/i, @{$1})
                  {
                    $flag = 1;
                   }

                else
                  {
                $flag = 0;
                   }
              }
          }

        if($flag == 1)
          {
            $/ = "%\n";
            $plm3 =~ /arr_(\w+.txt)/;
            open SUPARARE, "C:/downloads/text_files/replies/$1" or die $!;
            etc etc....
```

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but if you want to match a literal `.txt` you need to escape the dot in your regex: `/arr_(\w+\.txt)/`.

Comment: You should use strict and stop fiddling with symbolic refs:  `push( @{$1}, $_);`.  Did you come up with that plan, or did you copy that code from somewhere online?

Comment: i came up with it, i wanted to generate the arrays dynamically based on existing file names on the hard drive

Comment: @Benca It is almost always better to use explicit variable names than not. For example: `@{$file{$1}}` is much better than `@{$1}`.

Comment: @TLP, ok i'll try that too but i'm still in the dark, why that works in all the occurences in my code except in one:(, ty

Comment: @Benca Those "mysterious" errors very often come from not using `strict`. I'm not just saying that, I know that.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, it's always a good idea to use strict pragma -- unless you have a valid reason to avoid it --.

Second, I don't see $plm3 initialized anywhere in your code. You have probably forgot to initialize it.

Comment: yes, frist i wrote it with strict but when i changed it to take file and array names dynamically i had to abandon it, things like @{$1} didn't work with strict

Comment: right i initialized $plm3 and got rid of "Use of uninitialized value in pattern match (m//) at emo_full_dynamic.pl line 120, <STDIN> chunk 2." now i'm left only with "Modification of a read-only value attempted at emo_full_dynamic.pl line 121, <STDIN> chunk 2."
line 120 =  $plm3 =~ /arr_(\w+.txt)/;

Comment: @Benca Lucian: strict prevents you from doing things like @{$1} for a reason; it's generally very poor planning that brings you to using symbolic refs.  Just use a hash: my %arrays; push @{$arrays{$1}}, [ .... ];, for example is a preferable way.  See perlref and perlreftut from Perl's documentation.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are assigning something to variable `$1` on line 121

Answer (score 0):

Apparently there are some copy/paste issues which negates my initial answer.

Other mistakes, great and small:

- You don't use strict. (fatal flaw)
- Your opendir is used once, then never closed.
- You use global filehandles, instead of lexical (e.g. `open my $fh, ...`)
- Using a complext loop + `splice` instead of `grep` (`@files=grep /^arr/i, @files`)
- Using `chomp($_)` when chomp per default chomps the `$_` variable
- I don't even know what this line means:

  ```
      if(grep $stare  =~ m/$_/i, @{$1}) {
  ```

You seem to be using a pattern match, where `$_` is the pattern (which in this case is.. what? Nothing? Anything?), whose return value is used as a grep pattern for an array reference, that may or may not be initialized. A very horrible statement. If it indeed works as intended, the readability is very low.

- Redeclaring `$/` seems like a frivolous thing to do in this context, but I can't really tell, as the script ends there.

Comment: That part opens files that have a speciffic name format and then generates arrays with similar name and loads data from files to those arrays. Strangely that first "{" isn't in my code, it's  probably from the copy/paste and reindenting from editor to post, that part works fine, i fact all of it works fine except those last lines

Comment: @Benca Fix the other things I mention in my updated answer. Then please edit your question to include your new code, using a complete copy/paste.

Comment: @Benca And most importantly, add `use strict; use warnings;` It may seem like a lot of work to fix the errors, but in reality, you save a lot more time in the end, because the hidden bugs become visible.

Comment: @Benca Oh, sorry, I see you are using warnings. Well, then add `strict`.

Comment: I can't use strict for reasons stated above, i do use warnings it's right there in the code:), closing DIR handle is not part of the problem, "if(grep $stare  =~ m/$_/i, @{$1})" this lets me get a match when the input has more or less chars than the actual string i'm looking for, there are a lot of other validations that are not part of the problem so i didn't post them, soory for the low readability but it's perl after all:P, i need to redeclare $/ so that i can read elements from some files that are have a different separators, thanks for the other tips though, appreciated very much

Comment: @Benca If "reasons stated above" is about creating symbolic references to arrays, that can be solved with a hash of arrays. Like I said, `strict` saves you trouble, it does not add to them. And why are you using `$_` in your pattern match? What does it contain, and are you sure that that value never changes? Also, perl has perfectly fine readability, **if** you write readable code.

Comment: @TLP yes i'm 100% sure about that "$_", and at that time it was the only thing i could come up with, i'll try to solve my problem with hashes if there is no other alternative, thanks very much for all the help

Comment: @Benca It sounds like you want no more help, perhaps you are overwhelmed, so I'll leave you with my last observation: `$_` seems to contain whatever was last read from the filehandle `ARR`. The bad thing about using `$_` here is that it can change in non-obvious places, leading to very obscure bugs.